# Strstr alternatives

Tags: php, html, syntax

The strstr() function searches for the first occurrence of a string inside another string.
 My question is, is there an alternative to strstr that searches for all occurrences?

Comment: You could explode the string and then see if there's a match exactly from there and return the count

Comment: Sounds like what you are looking for is `preg_match_all`

Comment: I guess it depends on what you want to do with "all occurrences" - for example if you are looking for "cat" in "catdogcat" and you want to remove the "cat" then str_replace() is the tool.  If you want to know how many, substr_count() is right.  If you need positional data strpos() will solve it for you.  If you give us some test data, we can probably give you a tested and working code sample.

Comment: given `$haystack = 'aabaaa'; $needle = 'aa';` what should the results be? Think carefully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php might do it for you.

These are added bytes to make SO accept a succinct answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `preg_match_all` it is looking for all occurrences matching a regular expression pattern.

This will work slightly other than strstr
http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php

Depending on how exactly you are using `strstr` you'll define your expression.

If required, I can help you with this once the exact use is clear

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
// get last directory in $PATH
$dir = substr(strrchr($PATH, ":"), 1);

// get everything after last newline
$text = "Line 1\nLine 2\nLine 3";
$last = substr(strrchr($text, 10), 1 );
?>
```

Comment: Any,chance you can add an explanation of this?